# Floating Aciton Button Ripple Color

Tags: material-ui

I am using the FloatingActionButton, but not in the way it was originally intended. Therefore I have changed the background-color to white, and changed the IconColor. I get the icon using `react-icons`, and not the Material UI's own.

```
const iconStyle = {
  height: 64,
  width: 64,
  fill: 'green',
  color: 'green'
};

...

render(){
    return (
                    <FloatingActionButton
                    backgroundColor= 'white'
                    style={ buttonStyle }
                    iconStyle={ iconStyle }
                    zDepth={ 1 }>
                        {this.props.children}
                    </FloatingActionButton>
        );
```

How does one go about changing the ripple color on a component specific level?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to define custom theme.

```
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  floatingActionButton : {
    iconColor : '#666'        // desired ripple color
  }
});

render() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
      <FloatingActionButton
        backgroundColor= 'white'
        style={ buttonStyle }
        iconStyle={ iconStyle }
        zDepth={ 1 }
      >
          {this.props.children}
      </FloatingActionButton>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Also, don't forget to import **getMuiTheme** and **MuiThemeProvider**

```
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
```

More information can be found here.
http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes